# Write text on existing table/Image using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

[image: This is my pdf screenshot]

There is an existing table/image. When I write text using pdfcontentbyte, it is written behind this table/image.

I also want to write the text from the right side of this table/column.

The code I'm currently using to produce the image above:

```
 // open the reader
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldFile);
 iTextSharp.text.Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
 Document document = new Document(size);
 // open the writer
 FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
 PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
 document.Open();
 PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
 BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.COURIER_BOLD,BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
 string text = "WV0501";
 cb.BeginText();
 // put the alignment and coordinates here
 cb.ShowTextAligned(2, text, 155, 655, 0);
 cb.EndText();
 // create the new page and add it to the pdf 
  PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
  cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

 document.Close();
 fs.Close();
 writer.Close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't show us your code, so we have to guess what you are doing wrong.

**The content isn't showing:**

You probably have this line in your code:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = pdfStamper.GetUnderContent(page);
```

If so, you should replace it with this line:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(page);
```

**Update after you showed us your code:**

You want to add content to an existing document, yet you are using a combination of `Document` and `PdfWriter`. Why are you doing this? Please read chapter 6 of my book where you'll learn about `PdfStamper`.

Right now, you are adding the text first and then you are covering it with a page from an existing document. This means that the existing page will cover the text.

You can switch this around like this:

```
 // create the new page and add it to the pdf 
 PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
 cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
 BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.COURIER_BOLD,BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
 string text = "WV0501";
 cb.BeginText();
 // put the alignment and coordinates here
 cb.ShowTextAligned(2, text, 155, 655, 0);
 cb.EndText();
```

Now the text will cover the page, but that doesn't mean your code is better. You should really use `PdfStamper` instead of `PdfWriter`:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldFile);
FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs);
PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.COURIER_BOLD,BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(
        canvas,
        Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, 
        new Phrase("WV0501", new Font(bf, 9)), 
        155, 655, 0
    );
stamper.Close();
```

Don't you agree that this is more elegant?

**IMPORTANT:**

In your code you use:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.COURIER_BOLD,BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

However, that doesn't make much sense: `COURIER_BOLD` is one of the Standard Type 1 fonts and because of that the `embedded` parameter is ignored. I changed this into `NOT_EMBEDDED` because if you use `EMBEDDED` developers who read your code and who don't know anything about PDF and iText may get confused. They might ask: *Why is the font not getting embedded when the parameter says it should be embedded?*

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.COURIER_BOLD,BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
```

**Writing from the right side:**

You are defining the alignment using a number: `2`. I suggest that you don't use a number in your code, but a constant: `ALIGN_RIGHT`. This way, we see that you want to right align the text.

The text is right aligned with respect to the coordinates you've defined:

```
x = 155
y = 655
```

If you are not happy with the position of your text, you should change these hard-coded coordinates. For instance: increase `x` and decrease `y`.

You probably want the text to be relative to the border of a table cell or an image. If that is the case, you should not hard-code the coordinates.
Retrieving the coordinates of an image is discussed in another question on SO. Retrieving the coordinates of a table might very well be impossible. It all depends on the nature of the original PDF.

Comment: You should have added your code rightaway. That way we wouldn't have had to guess. In any case: you are doing it wrong. Probably because you didn't read the documentation. It's hard to tell. Your code snippet doesn't show what you do with `PdfReader`. All in all, it's not a good question.

Comment: Thanks for describing about alignmet, and i am initializing pdfwriter in pdfconentbyte so how will i call this method GetOverContent(page)

Comment: That may solve your problem, but that doesn't mean your code isn't wrong. Why aren't you using `PdfStamper`?

Comment: I have edited my question since you are mixing all kinds of things that you shouldn't mix. Please answer this simple question: *Why are you using PdfWriter instead of PdfStamper?* (It wouldn't be friendly if you ignored this question.)

Comment: i dont know how to use pdfstamper and make new pdf by adding new text in exixting pdf. I will accept your valuable suggestion

Comment: its working fine  but its showing default font even i called this method SetFontAndSize(basefont,9) please reply

Comment: I'll update my answer. It would also help if you read [the documentation](http://itextpdf.com/learn) because you shouldn't use `SetFontAndSize()` outside a text object and I sincerely hope you don't nest text objects. Maybe you don't realize that, but in the code snippet in your question, you are using syntax that should only be used if you know PDF syntax very well. In my example, I use syntax that hides the complexity.

Comment: Wow great thanks alot i was confused because i am working very first time for itextsharp and having very little dead line to complete tha task.
kindly tell me if i need more text to add some where "not on image" so should i also write it the way you told?? or like i was doing it before??

Comment: I don't understand the question. Did you read chapter 6 of my book? Please take a look at the table in the Summary. It explains which class to use in which case. If you work with **a single, existing PDF**, use `PdfStamper`.

Comment: img.ScaleToFit(210f, 31f);
in my image object i am setting this height and width, but its width is still 160 how can i increase that ??? kindly help..

Comment: Please post this as a new question and tell us more about the original width and height of the image. `ScaleToFit()` isn't the same as `ScaleAbsolute()`! Maybe it's normal that the width is still 160 (for instance because the height is 31).

Comment: ScaleToFit(), this method worked, it made the image width which i needed once again thanks a lot :)  @Bruno Lowagie